# Configure input_map when importing a tensorflow model from metagraph file

Tags: tensorflow

I've trained a DCGAN model and would now like to load it into a library that visualizes the drivers of neuron activation through image space optimization.

The following code works, but forces me to work with (1, width, height, channels) images when doing subsequent image analysis, which is a pain (the library assumptions about the shape of network input).

```py
# creating TensorFlow session and loading the model
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)

new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_fn)
new_saver.restore(sess, './')
```

I'd like to change the input_map, After reading the source, I expected this code to work:

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)

t_input = tf.placeholder(np.float32, name='images') # define the input tensor
t_preprocessed = tf.expand_dims(t_input, 0)

new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_fn, input_map={'images': t_input})
new_saver.restore(sess, './')
```

But got an error:

> ValueError: tf.import_graph_def() requires a non-empty `name` if `input_map` is used.

When the stack gets down to `tf.import_graph_def()` the name field is set to import_scope, so I tried the following:

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)

t_input = tf.placeholder(np.float32, name='images') # define the input tensor
t_preprocessed = tf.expand_dims(t_input, 0)

new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_fn, input_map={'images': t_input}, import_scope='import')
new_saver.restore(sess, './')
```

Which netted me the following `KeyError`:

> KeyError: "The name 'gradients/discriminator/minibatch/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3_grad/TensorArrayReadV3/RefEnter:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'gradients/discriminator/minibatch/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3_grad/TensorArrayReadV3/RefEnter', does not exist in the graph."

If I set 'import_scope', I get the same error whether or not I set 'input_map'.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: If you have a self-contained example, I'm happy to look at it. You can see how the `input_map` is used in the [test](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph_test.py#L262). I would try to go as close as possible to the test and see where it diverges.

Comment: @drpng There's a complete example in the github issue I opened (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7634). Thanks for recommending looking at the test. I'll try the approach it lays out for the lower level functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the newer version of tensorflow>=1.2.0, the following step works fine.

```
t_input = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=[None, width, height, channels], name='new_input') # define the input tensor

# here you need to give the name of the original model input placeholder name
# For example if the model has input as; input_original=  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, width, height, channels, name='original_placeholder_name'))
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(/path/to/checkpoint_file.meta, input_map={'original_placeholder_name:0':  t_input})
new_saver.restore(sess, '/path/to/checkpointfile')
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the main issue is that you're not using the syntax right. Check the documentation for `tf.import_graph_def` for the use of `input_map` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def)).

Let's breakdown this line:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_fn, input_map={'images': t_input}, import_scope='import')
```

You didn't outline what `model_fn` is, but it needs to be a path to the file.
For the next part, in `input_map`, you're saying: *replace* the input in the *original graph* (DCGAN) whose `name` is `images` with my variable (in the current graph) called `t_input`. Problematically, `t_input` and `images` are referencing the same object in different ways as per this line:

```
 t_input = tf.placeholder(np.float32, name='images')
```

In other words, `images` in `input_map` should actually be whatever the variable name is that you're trying to replace in the DCGAN graph. You'll have to import the graph in its base form (i.e., without the `input_map` line) and figure out what the name of the variable you want to link to is. It'll be in the list returned by `tf.get_collection('variables')` after you have imported the graph. Look for the dimensions (1, width, height, channels), but with the values in place of the variable names. If it's a placeholder, it'll look something like `scope/Placeholder:0` where `scope` is replaced with whatever the variable's scope is.

Word of caution:

Tensorflow is very finicky about what it expects graphs to look like. So, if in the original graph specification the width, height, and channels are explicitly specified, then Tensorflow will complain (throw an error) when you try to connect a `placeholder` with a different set of dimensions. And, this makes sense. If the system was trained with some set of dimensions, then it only knows how to generate images with those dimensions.

In theory, you can still stick all kinds of weird stuff on the front of that network. But, you will need to scale it down so it meets those dimensions first (and the Tensorflow documentation says it's better to do that with the CPU outside of the graph; i.e., before inputing it with `feed_dict`).

Hope that helps!