# Concatenating two saved models in tensorflow 1.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I've a pretrained model saved as ckpt files (meta, index ...) and I'm loading the graph using `tf.train.import_meta_graph()` and `tf.train.Saver.restore()`.
I also have a resnet50 model from `tf.keras.applications`.
I need to give output of resnet model to the model I load from the disk.
How can I achieve that?

Code:

```
resnet_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg')
preprocessed_video = preprocess_input(tf.cast(video, tf.float32))
features = self.resnet_model([preprocessed_video])

sess1 = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path.as_posix() + '.meta')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
saver.restore(sess1, model_path.as_posix())
input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input/Identity:0')
result = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output/Identity:0')
```

I need to give `features` to `input_x` and get `result`. Note that, this has to happen while building the graph and not while running `sess.run`. I mean, `video`, `features` are all `tensors` and not `numpy.ndarray`. So, I can't use `sess.run`

**Edit 1**:
As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630180/3337089), I could solve as below:

```
preprocessed_video = preprocess_input(tf.cast(video, tf.float32))
features = self.resnet_model([preprocessed_video])
sess1 = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path.as_posix() + '.meta', input_map={'input/Identity:0': features})
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
saver.restore(sess1, model_path.as_posix())
quality_score = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output/Identity:0')
```

Thanks [jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782792/jdehesa)