# Assign tensor value to placeholder in tensorflow v1.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

In my tensorflow model, output of one network is a tensor. This value I need to feed as input to another pretrained network. I'm loading the pretrained network as follows

```
input_b_ph = tf.placeholder(shape=(), dtype=float.32, name='input_b_ph')
sess1 = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path.as_posix() + '.meta', input_map={'input/Identity:0': input_b_ph})
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
saver.restore(sess1, model_path.as_posix())
output_b = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output/Identity:0')
```

I need to feed a tensor to `feature_input`. How can I achieve this?

**Edit 1**: Adding end-to-end details:
I have a network `A` defined in tensorflow which takes input `input_a` and produces output `output_a`. This I need to feed to ResNet50 pretrained model. For this I used `ResNet50` from `tf.keras`

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input

resnet_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg')
preprocessed_input = preprocess_input(tf.cast(output_a, tf.float32))
output_resnet = resnet_model([preprocessed_input])
```

Output of ResNet is `output_resnet`. This I need to feed to another pretrained network, say network `B`. `B` is actually written in Keras. I modified it to use `tf.keras`. Then I save the trained model as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
curr_sess = keras.backend.get_session()
with tf.name_scope('input'):
    _ = tf.identity(quality_net.model.input)
with tf.name_scope('output'):
    __ = tf.identity(quality_net.model.output)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(curr_sess, output_filepath.as_posix())
```

I have access to this network `B` and tried to save the model in `h5` format but it gave error that model is thread lock. On searching in internet, I got to know this error comes when there are `Lambda` layers in the network. So, I resorted to saving the model in tensorflow format - 3 files: meta, weights and index. (Any solution using h5 format is also acceptible).

There is a caveat here. That the structure of network `B` can keep changing and it is from a different project. So I can't hardcode the architecture of `B`. I've to load it from saved model. My problem is how can I restore this pretrained model and pass `output_resnet` as input to network `B`. The output of network `B` i.e. `output_b` is the loss function to train my original network `A`. Currently I'm able to restore network B as follows:

```
input_b_ph = tf.placeholder(shape=(), dtype=float.32, name='input_b_ph')
sess1 = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path.as_posix() + '.meta', input_map={'input/Identity:0': input_b_ph})
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
saver.restore(sess1, model_path.as_posix())
output_b = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output/Identity:0')
```

I have output from resnet as `output_resnet` which is a tensor. I need a way to set this to `input_b_ph`. How can I achieve that? Any alternate solutions are also acceptible

Comment: I suppose this has to do with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59084901/1782792), but I'm not sure I understand the difference, or just what exactly you need to achieve in this case. You want to be able to do something like `session.run(out, feed_dict={feature_input: x})`, where `x` is a `tf.Tensor`? That is not possible (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42560209/1782792)), if you want to connect the output of one model to the input of the next, `feature_input` should be the `tf.Tensor` produced by the first model instead of a placeholder.

Comment: Yes, this is in continuation to previous question. Yes I know feeding tensor to placeholder is not possible. I've updated my question with my problem in detail. Please take a look at that and let me know if there is any way possible. Thanks. Ask me if you need any further clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. I'm sorry, though, I'm still not sure I understand completely. Can not you simply pass `input_map={'input/Identity:0': output_resnet}`?

Comment: Will that work? Shouldn't a placeholder be passed to input_map? I'll try that (tomorrow). Thanks

Comment: Yes, any tensor value should be okay, see if that works.

Comment: Yes. It did work. Thanks a ton! Would you mind writing it as answer. I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning the Answer in this (Answer) Section (although it is present in Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

`Placeholder` is not required in this case. Just passing `output_resnet` to `input_map` should resolve the issue.

Replacing the code,

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path.as_posix() + '.meta', 
                                        input_map={'input/Identity:0': input_b_ph})
```

with

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path.as_posix() + '.meta', 
                                      input_map={'input/Identity:0': output_resnet})
```

has resolved the issue.